# Prevent Android Chrome scrolling to focused item when interacting with Media controls

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

On mobile Chrome (Android in this case), When a user has a focus on a text item (eg input), and then clicks on Media controls (<video>,<audio>). Chrome will scroll back the page to the focused item.

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/xn0f9uv3/1/show

[Demo Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKAzG.gif)

If I could blur the focus, the scrolling does not happen. However the `audio` element does not seem to trigger any mousedown/touchstart events. The `video` element triggers touchstart, but NOT if you click the play, seek or volume controls. `onplay` event fires too late. `onblur` event does not help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I experience the same problem, but with input range instead of video element.

Comment: @DenysPotapov I have filled a bug for Chrome, but no official fix yet. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1269037

Comment: Are there any news on this issue? Did you maybe find an alternative solution?